# How to create a Serializer for a List<Pair<String, Any>>

Tags: kotlin, serialization, android-jetpack-compose, key-value, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to create a Serializer for the `List<Pair<String, Any>>` type, I need this type for a project where I have to manipulate keys and values but user can change key names at any time and using a List of Pair is much better for what I want (and doesn't really work with a Map).

I have this code, but it produces a [compiler error](https://pastebin.com/QGx2PuER)

```kotlin
class SnapshotListPairSerializer<K, V>(private val keySerializer: KSerializer<K>, private val valueSerializer: KSerializer<V>) :
    KSerializer<SnapshotStateList<Pair<K, V>>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = ListSerializer(PairSerializer(keySerializer, valueSerializer)).descriptor
    
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: SnapshotStateList<Pair<K, V>>) {
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(ListSerializer(PairSerializer(keySerializer, valueSerializer)), value as List<Pair<K, V>>)
    }
    
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): SnapshotStateList<Pair<K, V>> {
        val list = mutableStateListOf<Pair<K, V>>()
        val items = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(ListSerializer(PairSerializer(keySerializer, valueSerializer)))
        list.addAll(items)
        return list
    }
}
```

Also, `SnapshotStateList` is a class that comes from [`Jetpack Compose`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateList) and extends `List`.

Comment: (The PasteBin link gives `Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation.` — Which is of course one reason why it's often better to include stuff like that directly in the question where possible.)

Comment: Your code compiles fine to me. Please don't use links to your code/errors on SO questions, instead use formatted significant part of the code/stack trace.

Comment: Sorry the link was working some days ago, I'll change it, but my stacktrace is like 3000 lines long with a lot of compiler code and compiler saying "there and there and there I'm not working".

Comment: The error is now public on pastebin.

Comment: Thank you for the full stack trace. But still, could you please include the _main_ points of the exception you get in the question, i.e., the exception, as been suggested twice now? "Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering" It not only prevents problems like this, it is friendlier to those trying to help you, _and_ ensures the essence of your question can more easily end in Google results in return helping others. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get is:

> Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering

Given that this is not providing you with meaningful information, but mentions compiler internals, this is not an error of your doing, but a bug: a cue to search for known bugs.

This seems very similar to the [issue I filed on GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1770).

If it is the same cause, it should be fixed in version 1.6.10. This may explain why [Philip can't repro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70513418/how-to-create-a-serializer-for-a-listpairstring-any#comment124649326_70513418).

P.s. the next problem you will run into is likely that `Any` is not registered for [polymorphic serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md). Serializing `Any` is dodgy. If you are stuck and the documentation does not help you out, I suggest you post a new question with more information on the exact use case/expected types, and I will gladly help out.

Comment: Okay, I do not know that, thanks ! But for my side I just used a basic List serializer instead of one for List of pairs, and it worked gently ^^